# Call custom JS Object from vue file

Tags: vue.js

I have a custom object `Plan` which is being used by multiple files in my project. Currently I just redeclare the custom object `Plan` wherever it's being called. It's inefficient, so I wanted to put this custom object in a single file `Plan.js` and just call it whenever I need it. Here's what I did:

`Plan.js`

```
exports.Plan = {
    SK: '',
    selectPlan: '',
    selectPlanOthers: '',
    total: '',
    howTo: '',
    details: '',
    emailTo: '',
};
```

The problem is I cannot call Plan from any of my Vue file. Here's what I did to try to call it:

```
import Plan from './../model/Plan';
```

But the statement above will return the error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module './../model/Plan'. 'e:/web/kesayangan/src/model/Plan.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Comment: try `export const Plan = {}`

Comment: @Dimava still the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'a TS error.

You can:

- Create `Plan.d.ts` for type support
- ...or rename `Plan.js` to `Plan.ts`

Comment: I already did that.. renamed the file to Plan.ts, and now gets the error: File 'Plan.ts' is not a module

Comment: @imin try to use ES Module Import/Export